# first portion of route url is not included

Tags: node.js, api, express, redirect

I have a route where I built two `GET APIs`. I would like one to redirect from `/download` to `/zip` all while passing a parameter. The problem is I am getting a 404 for some reason the routes url is not being included in the `redirect()`

Here are the APIs.

```
// respond with xml from from static folder
router.get('/zip/:id', function (req, res) {

    fileName = req.params.id

});

router.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.query.id
    res.redirect('/zip?id='+ id);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I get a 404 when testing the `URL`:
`localhost:8000/rest/pluto/v1/plugin/download?id=networktool`

I am thinking it might be how I have the middleware setup but not real sure. I'm still new to node/express.

Comment: I should also mention, I can break on `var id = req.query.id` the `404` happens when I try to redirect to `/zip?id='+id`

Comment: It could be that how you defined the `zip` route, it is expecting an :id in the url path but you are trying to redirect to it with the id as a query parameter

Comment: I updated it with `res.redirect('/zip'+ id);` and still get the same error.

Comment: When I change the redirect to: `res.redirect('/rest/pluto/v1/plugin/zip/'+ id);` it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting to a route that isn't actually defined. With your `/zip/:id` route definition:

```
router.get('/zip/:id', function (req, res) {
    var fileName = req.params.id
});
```

The way that is defined, you **have** to have *id* information in the URL itself, so while the following routes would work:

```
/zip/networktool
/zip/1234
```

these routes would not:

```
/zip
/zip?id=networktool
/zip?id=1234
```

because Express is looking for the id to be built into the route itself. So you can do one of two things. You can either change your redirect to:

```
router.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/zip/'+ req.query.id);
});
```

or, you can modify your `/zip` route to make the `id` parameter optional with `?`:

```
router.get('/zip/:id?', function (req, res) {
    var fileName = (req.params.id) ? req.params.id : req.query.id;
});
```

I would recommend the first option, as the latter optional parameter only makes your `zip` route more complicated and require extra handling of whether `id` is actually passed to your route.

Comment: When I change the redirect to: `res.redirect('/rest/pluto/v1/plugin/zip/'+ id);` it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you defined your route to have a prefix, so when you call the redirect you have to add that prefix to the route.

Answer (score 1):

The path `/zip/:id` is expecting a path parameter not a query parameter.

You should redirect like this

```
res.redirect('/zip/'+ id);
```

Comment: When I change the redirect to: `res.redirect('/rest/pluto/v1/plugin/zip/'+ id);` it works. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your router was configured to have the prefix `/rest/pluto/v1/plugin/`

Comment: Here is how it is configured  in `app.js`
`var plugin = require('./routes/plugin');`

`app.use(tools.getUrlPrefix() + '/v1/plugin', plugin);`

Comment: So that explains it, all of your endpoints in `plugin` will have that prefix.